# Check post's category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

For example, I have 4 . I want to check if post had category1, i will put it in div1, category2 in div2 and so on.How can I do it? Does WP has any functions that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`has_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) function:

```
if ( has_category('somecat') ) {
    // Do something
}
```